# How to solve syntax error, unexpected token, export type?

Tags: node.js, typescript, react-native, react-navigation, node-modules

I was using version `2.x` of `react-navigation`, now I'm migrating to version `5.x`. I have installed all modules according to the documentation, but on running the application, I get this error.

It seems more like a typescript compilation error, but I'm not sure why it appeared, as I simply ran `npm install` command and have not touched any `node_module` files.

```
error: SyntaxError: E:\PROJECTS\rnzone\BoxApp\node_modules\@react-navigation\stack\src\index.tsx: Unexpected token (51:12)

  49 |  * Types
  50 |  */
> 51 | export type {
     |             ^
  52 |   StackNavigationOptions,
  53 |   StackNavigationProp,
  54 |   StackHeaderProps,
```

What do you suggest?

Comment: Maybe helpful link (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7978#issuecomment-610934738)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So I was able to solve this by upgrading `@babel/core` and `@babel/runtime` in dev dependencies.

Support for type-only imports + exports was added in 7.9.0

Thanks to nickyleach for pointing [this](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7981#issuecomment-611419607) out.

Comment: It doesn't work with the latest `@babel/core` and `@babel/preset-typescript`.

Answer (score 1):

If the above isn't working, add `@babel/core` as a **global** dependency (`yarn global add @babel/core` / `npm install -g @babel/core`), because globally-installed `expo-cli` won't recognize project-based babel installations for some reason.

Comment: Installing `@babel/core` globally has no effect.

Comment: @Distortum It's something along those lines. If you wanna be extra sure, remove `expo-cli` and all `babel` packages from global and install them on a per-project basis. It's a better practice anyway (and also what I ended up doing).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps to resolve the issue,

- `npm install @babel/core@^7.9.0`
- `npm install @babel/runtime@^7.9.2`
- `npm install typescript@^3.8.3`
- `rm -rf node_modules`
- `npm install`
- Uninstall app in emulator/phone.
- `npm start -- --reset-cache`